# Ant Task get last modified file time

Tags: ant

I have an ant task to concatenate javascript files in a directory and output to concat.js  What I want to do is first check if any files have a later modified time than that of concact.js before proceeding.

Here is the existing task:

```
    <target name="minijs" depends="lintjs">

    <echo>Concatinating ${plugins.dir} to ${plugins.concat}</echo>
    <concat destfile="${plugins.concat}">
        <fileset dir="${plugins.dir}">
            <exclude name="**/vendor/**" />
            <exclude name="*beconcat*" />
            <include name="**/*.js" />
        </fileset>
    </concat>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what the `uptodate` task has been created for

`<uptodate property="isUpToDate"
          targetfile="${plugins.concat}">
  <srcfiles  dir="${plugins.dir}">
    <exclude name="**/vendor/**" />
    <exclude name="*beconcat*" />
    <include name="**/*.js" />
  </srcfiles>`

will set the property `isUpToDate` if none of the files is newer than the target file - and not set the property at all if one of the files is. You can then use `unless` to conditionally rebuild the file.